# Keeping "No" option in the drop down list is a good practice when I want to display all other options also?

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, visual-design

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcoCRb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm building a web application. I want to ask a user that do you know any of the following subjects (Here the options might be 20-30 also)?

Default selected option is "--Select--". 
User experience wise putting No in the dropdown is not looking good. But I want them to see the options. 
So any better suggestion? Or is it fine to keep No in the dropdown?

Answer (score 4):

This works if the option takes only 1 answer. What if the students know Physics, Maths and Chemistry too?

I will use checkboxes for this question.

"Check all that applies"

if this takes only 1 answer, I will put No inside the list...

But use a line to seperate them from the list. The List should be sorted alphabetical order as well.

[image]